# eel при запуске выдает ошибку

Tags: python, eel

```
partially initialized module 'eel' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

вот код

```
import eel


eel.init('web')


eel.start('index.html')
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что у объекта / класса `eel` есть метод `init`?

Comment: А код, который в вопросе, случайно не в файле, имя которого 'eel.py'?

Comment: @void Судя по всем признакам скорее всего так и есть )